# Where I can define a global variable in an MFC application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I want to declare a global variable inside an MFC application, so that every action inside the application can see this variable and manipulate it, but I don't know where exactly I can declare that variable. in this code i have many button actions, i need to declare a string variable that's shared among this actions.

```
// CalculatorDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Calculator.h"
#include "CalculatorDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
 public:
CAboutDlg();

 // Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };
public:
static CString myValue;

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

  // Implementation
protected:
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD) {}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CCalculatorDlg dialog


CCalculatorDlg::CCalculatorDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CCalculatorDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CCalculatorDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCalculatorDlg, CDialog)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON6, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton6)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON5, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton5)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON4, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton4)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON9, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton9)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON8, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton8)
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON7, &CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton7)
 END_MESSAGE_MAP()
 // CCalculatorDlg message handlers

     BOOL CCalculatorDlg::OnInitDialog()
    {
CDialog::OnInitDialog();

// Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

// IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
    CString strAboutMenu;
    strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
    if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
    {
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
    }
}

// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
//  when the application's main window is not a dialog
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

// TODO: Add extra initialization here

return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
 }

 void CCalculatorDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
 {
if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
{
    CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
    dlgAbout.DoModal();
}
else
{
    CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
 }

 // If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
 //  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
 //  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CCalculatorDlg::OnPaint()
{
if (IsIconic())
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

    // Center icon in client rectangle
    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    // Draw the icon
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
}
else
{
    CDialog::OnPaint();
}
  }

 // The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
 //  the minimized window.
 HCURSOR CCalculatorDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
 {
return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
  }


 void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
/*
CString s="ABC";
    LPCTSTR str_name = _T("Hello ")*/;
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1,_T"9");
/*CAboutDlg::myValue="9";*/
}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton3(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton2(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton6(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton5(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton4(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton9(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton8(){}

void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton7(){}
```

Comment: exactly how you'd define one in a regular application.

Comment: What's the specific purpose of the global variable?    Avoiding the use of global variables is a common bit of advice handed out to anybody learning to program.   - I'd suggest reading and understanding the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad?lq=1 then take a step back and look at the alternatives

Comment: i want to declare a string variable that's shared among many actions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project uses precompiled headers (with 99.9999% probability it uses it as default MFC project setting), you can *declare* this variable in precompiled header file, typically its name is `stdafx.h` and *define* it in global scope of any appropriate translation unit (`.cpp` file). Typically this could be `YourProjectName.cpp` file that contains application class derived from `CWinApp`.

```
// stdafx.h
extern int globalVar; // Global variable declaration, note extern keyword

// YourProjectName.cpp - global scope
int globalVar = 42; // Global variable definition
```

Precompiled header `stdafx.h` is included first in every `.cpp` file of project, so `globalVar` will be available everywhere in your project code.

Also would like to mention that global objects are not recommended to be used, it's considered as [bad design and anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

Comment: i added the variable inside stdafx.h but it doesn't compile

Comment: @Eslam What is variable type? Where did you put it exactly in stdafx.h? Most appropriate place is the end of stdafx.h.

Answer (score 1):

Put the global variable in a header file and add it to [Name Forced Include File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).